# Image processing with Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: image-processing, hadoop

I am doing a project on [motion estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_estimation) between two frames of a video sequence using [Block Matching Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-matching_algorithm) and using [SAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences) metrics. It involves computing SAD between each block of reference frame and each block of a candidate frame in window size to get the motion vector between the two frames.

I want to implement the same using Map Reduce. Splitting the frames in key-value pairs, but am not able to figure out the logic because everywhere I see I find the wordCount or query search problem which is not analogus to mine

I would also appreciate If you are able to provide me more Map Reduce examples.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't design a solution for your overly broad problem here.

Comment: thomas thanks for correcting me, but it would greatly help if you provided me with some more examples of Hadoop Usage

Comment: Look at the examples package: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/package-summary.html

Comment: there is no explanation of any sort for these problems.Kindly provide a more useful link

Comment: What do "Join/Grep/Sort" need for an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is being used in situations where computations can happen in parallel and using a single machine might take a lot of time for the processing. There is nothing stopping you using Hadoop for video processing. Check [this](http://atbrox.com/2011/05/16/mapreduce-hadoop-algorithms-in-academic-papers-4th-update-may-2011/) and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/PoweredBy) for more information on where Hadoop can be used. Some of these are related to video processing.

Start with understanding the WordCount example and Hadoop in general. Run the example on Hadoop. And then work from there. Would also suggest to buy the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do) book. Hadoop and its ecosystem is changing at a very fast pace and it's tough to keep up-to-date, but the book will definitely give you a start on Hadoop.