# Want to process images with hadoop

Tags: image, image-processing, hadoop, mapreduce

My idea is to process large sets of images with hadoop mapreduce. How to approach image processing with hadoop ?

Comment: I have seen this kind of question multiple times on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368512/create-mapreduce-job-with-an-image-as-an-input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752772/hadoop-how-to-access-many-photo-images-to-be-processed-by-map-reduce

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552306/image-processing-with-hadoop-mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

You can import the images into a [sequence files](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile). Then when you'd run a map/reduce over that handling different images would be distributed amongs the mappers

Answer (score 0):

[HIPI](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/) can also be used for processing images with MR, but HIP has not been [updated](https://github.com/uvagfx/hipi) for over an year.